Help with showing $M$ is path connected if and only if $M$ is connected and locally path-connected
I'm trying to solve problem 10 of chapter 3's exercises in Elementary Classical Analysis by Jerold Marsden and Michael Hoffman. The problem asks

A metric space $M$ is said to be locally path-connected if each point in $M$
has a neighborhood $U$ such that $U$ is path-connected. (This terminology
differs somewhat from that of some topology books.) Show that ($M$ is
connected and locally path-connected) $\iff$ ($M$ is path-connected).

This means that to verify this relationship I should first prove that if $M$ is a connected and locally-path connected then $M$ is also path connected. Then I should prove that if $M$ is path connected then it is locally path-connected since I know that if $M$ is path connected it is connected from an earlier theorem. I understand proving the forward direction assuming I'm reading it correctly; however, I can't get a grip on how to prove $M$ is path connected $\implies $ $M$ is locally path-connected.

My most promising attempt was when I attempted a proof by contradiction which went as follows:

If $M$ is not locally path-connected then there exists $m\in M$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$, $D(m,\epsilon)$ contains two points which are not path connected within the neighborhood.
Let $A=\{x\in M: \text{there exists some neighborhood of $m$ such that $x$ is not connected to $m$}\}$

From there I would attempt to show that the set is open and closed as these usually go and then pair this with its complement to separate $M$ contradicting the fact that $M$ is connected, but I got stuck on proving that the set is open and closed. Additionally, I'm fairly certain that the complement is empty making it futile to separate $M$ using these sets.
Any hints on how to proceed would be appreciated. Thanks!

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your definitions, but couldn't you take $U=M$ to obtain a path connected neighborhood for any point?

That's what I thought to, but I got confused by the textbook's wording and assumed it had to be an epsilon neighborhood

@Boxonix In that case, am I misunderstanding what they mean by "neighborhood?"

A neighborhood is, to me, an open set that contains the point. Maybe your book defines it differently.

@Boxonix you are correct after a bit of digging. Thank you for directing me towards that detail though it should have been trivial. If you'd like to make an answer, I'd happily mark that as correct

No need to make it an answer. It's just semantics.

@Boxonix gotcha! Thanks again

It seems that the authors only consider subsets of some $\mathbb R^n$, not arbitrary metric spaces. But this point is irrelevant here. The definition of "locally path-connected" is

A metric space $M$ is said to be locally path-connected if each point in $M$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $U$ is path-connected. [Note that a neighborhood of $x$ is defined as an open set containing $x$; see Definition 7 in Section 2.7.]

In fact this differs substantially from the standard definition which is

$M$ is said to be locally path-connected if for each point  $x \in M$ and for each neighborhood $V$ of $x$ there exists a path-connected neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U \subset V$.

With the author's definition let us prove that

$M$ is connected and locally path-connected $\iff$ $M$ is path-onnected.

The $\Longleftarrow$ part is obvious. A path-connected space $M$ is known to  be connected and for each $x \in M$ we can take $U = M$ to verify local path-connectedness.
Concerning the proof of $\implies$ you had essentially the right idea.
Let $x \in M$ and $P(x)$ = set of all points $y \in M$ such that there exists a path from $x$ to $y$. Clearly $P(x) \ne \emptyset$ because $x \in P(x)$. We shall prove that $P(x)$ is open and closed in $M$ which shows $P(x) = M$.

$P(x)$ is open.
Let $y \in P(x)$. There exists a path $u :[0,1] \to M$ from $x$ to $y$ and a path-connected neighborhood $U_y$ of $y$. For each $z \in U$ there exists a path $v : [0,1] \to M$ from $y$ to $z$. Then the concatenation
$$u * v : [0,1] \to M, (u* v)(t) = \begin{cases}u(2t) & t \le 1/2 \\ v(2t-1) & t \ge 1/2 \end{cases}$$
is a path frm $x$ to $z$ which shows $U_y \subset P(x)$. Hence $P(x)$ is open.

$M \setminus P(x)$ is open.
Let $z \in M \setminus P(x)$. There exists a path-connected neighborhood $U_z$ of $z$. We claim that $U_z \subset M \setminus P(x)$ which proves 2.  Assume that $U_z$ is not contained in $M \setminus P(x)$. This means that there exists $y \in U_z \cap P(x)$. There is a path $u$ from $x$ to $y$ and a path $v$ from $y$ to $z$. Hence $u * v$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ which means $y \in P(x)$, a contradiction.


With the standard definition $\implies$ is still true, but $\Longleftarrow$ fails. A counterexample is the Warsaw circle which is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$. See e.g. the topologist's sine circle is path-connected but it's not locally path-connected.

Please don't answer duplicate questions.

@MartinBrandenburg it is no duplicate because the definition of "locally path-connected" is non-standard here.
